# Centos 6: Software Collections don't install correctly

Tags: centos, software-collections

On centos 6 (using Docker's `centos:6`), I've installed `centos-release-scl` and `scl-utils-build` via `yum`, but trying to run `scl` gives

> bash: scl: command not found

`find / -name scl` returns nothing, so I don't think it's a path issue.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What about installing `scl-utils.i686 : Utilities for alternative packaging` in addition to `scl-utils-build`??

Comment: `scl-utils.x86_64` does it. Thanks!!